# Terminate drag while mouse is still down

Tags: unity-game-engine

Imagine some standard Unity UI ScrollView. You grab it with your mouse and start dragging it so it is scrolling with your mouse. How do I programmatically make it stop scrolling while mouse button is still down? Is there any way to make ScrollRect think that user is released mouse button?

Comment: Why? On the ScrollView you can update the scrollPosition depending on the drag -> if the maximum is reached it will just stop scrolling further

Comment: @derHugo I need to make Drag&Drop functionality. When user drags item out of ScrollView, ScrollView need to stop following mouse.

Comment: Ah ok thanks for the aclaration, now I see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite old question, but I found exactly this same problem and no clean solution. My problem was to have scrollRect with items which I can scroll left/right but when user select one item and drag it up then scrollRect should cancel scrolling and allow user to drag item up. I achieved this by temporary setting `ScrollRect.enable` to `false`, and after few ms set it back to `true`.

Here is part of mu code which do this. Maybe somebody find this useful.

```
void Update()
{
    if (state == DragState.Started) {
        dragStart = Input.mousePosition;
        state = DragState.Continued;
    }

    if (state == DragState.Continued) {
        Vector3 pos = Input.mousePosition;
        if (pos.y - dragStart.y > 80) {
            scrollRect.enabled = false;
            state = DragState.None;
            Invoke("ReenableScroll", 0.01f);
        }
    }
}

private void ReenableScroll() {
    scrollRect.enabled = true;
}
```

Comment: Wow interesting solution! Not perfect but interesting, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Its not easy to make the EventSystem think something has happend while it hasn't. I believe its much easier to implement your own ScrollRect logic and parse the mouse input yourself

Answer (score 1):

You can call ScrollRect's OnEndDrag() method with artificial PointerEventData.

```
            var forceEndDragData = new PointerEventData(EventSystem.current)
            {
                button = PointerEventData.InputButton.Left
            };
            _scrollRect.OnEndDrag(forceEndDragData);
```